# Are laptop USBs GND same as house GND

Tags: usb, ground, safety, gpio

Can two devices powered by **two different power sources** (laptop's USB and house plug + transformer) communicate through GPIO without share GND?

If the GND isn't the same for the transformer and the laptop, the voltage gap can be huge. Such a gap can destroy or damage both devices, laptop and the transformer.

Is it safe to do this communication or should I add some **optocouplers** for galvanic isolation?

---

I mesure the voltage difference between the two grouds with a multimeter : few mV. Will the gap change over time?

Comment: That depends if the PSUs of your devices are isolated or not. If they are, they will float in relation to your house, and when you attach ones ground to another, they will be properly referenced.

Comment: If I connect both ground together they will have the same reference and then solve my "problem" ?

Comment: What is the GPIO reference for?

Comment: This is unclear, you need to specify *what* the devices are. You mention a GPIO, is this on the laptop or another device? How does the transformer factor in? If the ground is the same for the laptop and the device you can have a ground loop. If it isn't the same (and one of the devices is isolated, then the one ground  of the "plugged device" would be the ground for the system)

Comment: Laptops power supplies are usually isolated: the DC output is floating w.r.t. AC input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the laptop isn't plugged in, then no. It would be running on battery power alone.

If the laptop is plugged in, all bets are off. It depends on whether the laptop power adapter is earthed or not. Even if the plug does have an earth connection, there is no guarantee that it is connected to the laptop/USB ground.

In any case you don't want to be relying on earth for signalling. The noise will be terrible (e.g. mains hum), there is no guarantee the socket is properly earthed, etc.

Always run a GND wire with whatever signals you are running (unless they are differential using a scheme which doesn't require a common ground).

---

You can add isolation through an optocoupler if your signalling scheme allows. Whether or not that is needed will depend on what is at the other end. If for example you had a circuit which controlled whether a mains socket was turned on or off, you would definitely want some isolation there.

Comment: Note that even PSU with ground pin does not need to connect laptop's ground to outlet's ground (and it actually usually does not). The ground pin is used by EMI filter on mains line side in most cases, it is not connected to low voltage side.